# Customize Individual Page will shown in header menu after Specific product purchased in WooCommerce Order

Tags: redirect, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to while user purchase a specific product than after purchasing the product after that particular user while login his/her account and it will shown one hidden page in header menu.

I have tried lots of plugins and used some custom code but its not useable because of the code was working only after product purchase it will redirect on specific page.
But I am expecting the user will purchase the product then the user will login again that time in user account one hidden page will be shown in Header menu.